# Paypal UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile returning internal error

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing, paypal-nvp

I am trying to update a paypal recurrent payment profile with NVP. I want to change the payment amount. The request I am sending to is:

```
METHOD=UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile&VERSION=86&PWD=1404892100&USER=XXX@YYY.com&SIGNATURE=ASEEEEEEECCCCCCCC&ProfileID=I-8N1W7089GB47&Note=testing&Amount=105
```

This request is failing with the following message

```
[TIMESTAMP] => 2014%2d11%2d04T19%3a13%3a05Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 5c6026b1dedec
[ACK] => Failure
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10001
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Timeout processing request
```

The profile was created using express checkout and CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile api as instructed at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/

I have surfed the internet a lot but no solution is found. Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks
Monjur

Comment: This can sometimes happen if PayPal's server is experiencing a high volume of requests, but it shouldn't be a constant thing if that's the case.  If you're getting this every time, then it's probably a problem with the request.  Can you post a sample of the raw API request that you're generating and sending to PayPal?

Comment: The rreturn I am getting is: TIMESTAMP=2014%2d11%2d04T21%3a08%3a00Z&CORRELATIONID=b266f85d8a148&ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=10001&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Internal%20Error&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Timeout%20processing%20request

Comment: The request sent is: METHOD=UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile&VERSION=86&PWD=1404892100&USER=marslan.ali-facilitator_api1.gmail.com&SIGNATURE=AsH4KgWmXswD8zvjHqdfomcRAJtiA.7GTebv3aqgiinL2STjVlxk92Jb&ProfileID=I%2dMFUT9V97BJP6&Note=testing&Amount=110

Comment: You can check the details on http://monjur.fix-site.com/testpaypal/getProfile.php

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, did you find anything new?

Answer (score 0):

In your update request you've got the parameter name as AMOUNT instead of AMT.  Try adjusting that to see if you get a better response.

Comment: I have tried both AMT and Amount. Both gave the same rusult