# Is it possible to update recurring amount in paypal express checkout?

Tags: php, recurring-billing, paypal

I have integrated the paypal recurring using express checkout. The recurring profile created successfully.

I need to update the recurring billing amount before every recurring cycle. For that I am using 'UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile' hash call. But I am not able update the amount of recurring billing.
It is always giving me error.

My code is

```
$nvpstr="&PROFILEID=I-DB8HMA6R7F8T";
$nvpstr.="&AMT=".urlencode('50');
$nvpstr.="&CURRENCYCODE=USD";
$nvpstr.="&PAYMENTACTION=Order";
$nvpstr.="&BILLINGTYPE=RecurringPayments";

$resArray=hash_call("UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile",$nvpstr);
```

and response is:

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-12-27T10:26:00Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 7aa715c9e9ebe
    [ACK] => Failure
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10001
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Timeout processing request
)
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to update recurring amount in paypal express checkout?

Yes, it is (but not always) possible because there are limits in what is allowed to do to do and what not.

This is documented in detail in the [Integration Guide of Express Checkout under *Handling Recurring Payments*](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/).

---

For `UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile` the error code `10001` with short message `Internal Error` and long message `Timeout processing request` is *not* specified (see: [API Error and Warning Codes](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/)).

In cases the error is not specified, you need to contact Paypal support and ask for details.

According to Stackoverflow this problem happens from time to time:

- [Paypal UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile returning internal error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26743349/367456) (4 Nov 2014)
- [Is it possible to change only AMT using UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile PayPal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27186572/367456) (28 Nov 2014)

and users having it do not share any further information.

Comment: is it possible in express checkout to update amount for the recurring billing?

Comment: So if I need to update the amount of recurring billing with no limitation what should be the correct way using paypal express checkout?

Comment: You can't, there are always limits with that. Consult the documentation I linked, then you know if that what you want to do is possible or not. This can not be generally answered as it's not clear from your question what *exactly* you change and if you perhaps already hit any of the limits.

Comment: I have created the recurring profile with amount $1 initially. I need to update the recurring amount before next billing cycle. The amount can be anyting like $50 or $500. But dusing updating the amount it is always giving me the error.